# What are these white eggs behind my wall outlet?

Tags: electrical

What type of animal eggs are these white eggs? Do I have something to worry about?

[image]

Comment: If they are made of silk thread then probably spider's egg cases.

Comment: I hope you will at least rake them out and mush them up a bit, so that you do not find out the hard way too soon. It may reveal some info at least. My Google Lens app only show mushrooms as a possibility. But that is a picture of a picture, not the same as using Lens at the place of concern.

Answer (score 1):

Spider egg cases. Looks like they already hatched.